# create specific redirection url for specific user using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to create my web application.
My problem is I want to create specific redirection URL for specific user without login page. 
And I also want to check if the user input the wrong value for the URL parameter.

I have 3 user, each user can only see the different data based on the role.

```
Police - Criminal Data
Fire - Fire Data
Doctor - Patient Data
```

So, I want to setup the different URL for each of them.
    Expected URL:

```
~/DataDisplay.aspx?role=POLICE&password=1234

~/DataDisplay.aspx?role=FIRE&password=5678

~/DataDisplay.aspx?role=DOCTOR&password=1001
```

Then, after user type that URL in browser, another problem is I also want my website will check whether the role and password are input correctly, if not match, it will show ERROR!.

Need help, please.Thanks, Siti..:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ASP.NET membership. If you can extend easily for security and allow you to add more features if you want.

[Introduction of ASP.NET tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)